# mongo/express fetching user by id getting object = null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I have been trying to fetch user object by id, using  User.findById

postman returns "user": null, but the object which id I included in request contains fields.

my object example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3cac4d18ca463e9c6dc574"), 
    "local" : {
        "email" : "test@test.lt", 
        "password" : "$2a$08$fxzlQnxn7mKpIdLYXg8edeet1CJoZaG.Ube2pNpLEGLQEXYuVA47e"
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Here is my code:

User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  method: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'google', 'facebook'],
    required: true
  },
  local: {
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  google: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    }
  },
  facebook: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    }
  }
});
```

routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const passport = require('passport');
const router1 = express.Router();
require('../passport');

const { validateBody, schemas } = require('../helpers/routeHelpers');
const UsersController = require('../controllers/users');

const passportSignIn = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });
const passportJWT = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

router.route('/signup')
  .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema), UsersController.signUp);


router.route('/signin')
  .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema), passportSignIn, UsersController.signIn);

router.route('/get/:id')
  .get(UsersController.getUser);


router.route('/secret')
  .get(passportJWT, UsersController.secret);
```

controllers/users

```
module.exports = router;
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('../configuration');

const signToken = (user) => {
  return JWT.sign({
    iss: 'CodeWorkr',
    sub: user.id,
    iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
    exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time + 1 day ahead
  }, JWT_SECRET);
};

module.exports = {
  signUp: async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.value.body;

    // Check if there is a user with the same email
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ 'local.email': email });
    if (foundUser) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Email is already in use' });
    }
    // Create a new user
    const newUser = new User({
      method: 'local',
      local: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });

    await newUser.save();

    // Generate the token
    const token = signToken(newUser);
    // Respond with token
    return res.status(200).json({ token });
  },
  signIn: async (req, res) => {
    // Generate token
    const token = signToken(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({ token });
  }, 
  getUser: async (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id)
      .then((user) => {
        res.status(200).json({ user });
        console.log('test');
      });
  },

  secret: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('I managed to get here!');
    res.json({ secret: 'resource' });
  }
};
```

I have no idea, what to do is my object bad? Do i need to deep  clone it? Or use different function, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the model in mongose (in your User.js)

```
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And then when you want to query....

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
```

I think this is your issue, give it a try.

Comment: I did export my user schema in my model file just didn't wrote that to save time
// Create a model
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = User;

Did try including mongoose, but it did not work

Comment: if you debug User (in that file you are running the query) what do you get? also, what do you get if you debug user (the query result)

Comment: What do you by debu User? If i console log User which i import from schema
const User = require('../models/user') i get bunch of fields, when i try to use findbyid on User i just get object null, its the same if i use const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const user1 = mongoose.model('user'); the output is the same

Comment: enable mongoose logs and check the query is being done correctly (add them to the question). Check that req.params.id is set.

Comment: mongoose log:
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b3cac4d18ca463e9c6dc574") }, { fields: {} (maybe this is the problem fields are empty?) })
(node:12144) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
|
i do get req.params.id just console logged it

Comment: I am running out of ideas =P. Tried using `findOne({ _id: id })` ??

Comment: This is frustrating :/, same object null

Comment: Oh.... you need to add .exec() at the end. Find methods required that. find().exec().then...